# navigating JSON with variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So, i'm working with the following data...

```
var data = {"questions": {"question0": "what?", "question1": "why?", "question2": "where?"}};
```

and trying to loop through all questions, like so...

```
for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
   var value = "question"+n;
   var tracker = data.questions.value;
   console.log(tracker);
}
```

the problem is that i'm not sure how to declare *value* as a variable within *tracker*. Right now it's just looking for *value* nested within *questions* and not the actual output of *var value*.

Halp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *bracket* `[]` to wrap a variable as key:

```js
var data = {"questions": {"question0": "what?", "question1": "why?", "question2": "where?"}};

for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
   var value = "question"+n;
   var tracker = data.questions[value];
   console.log(tracker);
}
```